# ./command <<< several arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script

If I have a program called "prog" that requires only one argument, I can write:

```
./prog <<< 1
```

But if I have a program that requires 2 arguments why doesn't this work:

```
./prog <<< 2 3
```

I could not find an answer Googling. How can this work?

Note: I need this to write a `.sh`

Comment: `<<<` is not providing *argument(s)*, it is providing *input*.  A line of input consisting of `2`, space, `3`, and newline is *one line of input*, not two arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The `<<<` operator is documented in the `bash(1)` man page. It's for "here strings" (similar in concept to "here documents" that have been around in shell syntax for ages).

The syntax:

```
command <<< word
```

…expands `word` and passes it to `command` as standard input.

It's equivalent to:

```
echo word | command
```

If you really meant to pass both 1 and 2 as standard input (not arguments/parameters), you could do it with:

```
./command <<< "1 2"
```

or

```
./command <<< 1\ 2
```

Basically you need to escape the space between 1 and 2 to keep it from splitting the input into two words.

Answer (score -1):

I could not find any reference to the "<<<" operator for bash, but it did seem to take the text immediately after the operator and parse that as the first variable.

If you are writing a BASH script this is unneccessary.  You can simply use $X for each variable, and then add the variables to the script.  For example:

```
/bin/bash
echo "Usage:  $0 variable1 variable2"
echo "Variable 1 value is $1"
echo "Variable 2 value is $2"
```

So if you save the above file as "test.sh", make it executable run it as `./test.sh hello world`

It will output
Usage: ./test.sh variable1 variable2
Variable 1 value is hello
Variable 2 value is hello world

$0 = the name of the script.
If you want to pass 2 parameters with spaces, for example "Hello World" and "This is a test", you would call it as ./test.sh "Hello World" "his is a test"

Comment: Thanks @davidgo , in fact, my problem was not in the *.sh input rather in the program "prog" input. I wrote an answer with my solution.

Comment: Really?  You haven't read [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216) yet?

Answer (score -1):

**This is how I solved my problem:**

```
#/bin/bash
(echo 1 2)  |  ./prog
```